# Using .NET System.SpecialFolders or similar enum in node.js

Tags: .net, node.js, electron

I'm porting some code from c# to a node.js electron app. One of the components I'm working on relies on the [Environment.SpecialFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) enum. Specifically `SpecialFolders.Recent` and `SpecialFolders.ApplicationData`.

I've found I can use `process.env.APPDATA` to point to application data, and for some of the other components, I've written small executable wrappers and called them using `child_process.exec`, but this seems messy. I'd like to do everything inside of node. I've done some searching, but have not found a node or electron library that exposes the information I need. **I'm specifically looking for a javascript equivalent to `System.Environment.SpecialFolders.Recent`**

Comment: You need a library.  Something [like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/platform-folders) but not cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most special folders in Windows have an environment variable equivalent that you should be able to use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/knownfolderid

These percent encoded special folders should auto-expand when using in a **path**. There is also a node module that attempts to handle special folders in a cross-platform manner: https://www.npmjs.com/package/platform-folders

According to that documentation, Recent items defaults to **%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent**

Comment: I'll probably end up using a path relative to %APPDATA%. There are some hints that these folders may or may not be at their default location.

Comment: You've definitely lead me down the right path. It looks like I can resolve these names to paths using the values in the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\ specifically HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{AE50C081-EBD2-438A-8655-8A092E34987A} for recent files. Thanks!